# Chrome ctrl comma and ctrl period no longer able to traverse call frame?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

This stopped working recently, what happened? Is there a way I can configure it so that it would work?

Edit: So I verified with the following, apparently `CTRL + ,` still works as traverse up, but not `CTRL + .`

This is across multiple installations I use so it is in the latest chrome on all my Mac OS machines.

```js
(function a() {
    return function b() {
        debugger;
    }
})()()
```

## Edit

It appears Chrome recently (Apr 2019) fixed this issue.

Comment: Those are definitely listed [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts) so they should still work. Did you do a Chrome update between when they worked and when they stopped working? Do other shortcuts listed on that page still work?

Comment: A temporary workaround might be to build Chromium yourself, and modify the key bindings of the developer tools (see [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=174309#c56)).

Answer (score 1):

One thing that you can check is that if `Ctrl+.` and `Ctrl+,` is not mapped in operating system command shortcuts because it will take precedence over chrome shortcuts/shortkeys